# How to subset data by filtering and grouping efficiently in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table

I'm working on a project and am looking for some help to make my code run more efficiently. I've searched for similar problems but can't seem to find anything quite as granular as this one. The solution I've come up with is extremely clunky. I'm confident that there must be a more efficient way to do this with a package like `dplyr`, `data.tables`, etc.

**Problem:** I have 3 columns of data, `'ids'`, `'x.group'`, and `'times'`. I need to extract the first 3 unique `'ids'` that appear in each `'times'` block for each `'x.group'`.

However, I do not want to include any `'ids'` or `'x.group'` equal to "0". The output at the bottom of my code yields the correct values, but it's a rather embarrassing way of getting there in my opinion.

Note: In the code example below, I am using `x.groups = ['A','B','0']`, but in my actual project, these can take on many values, so they won't always be 'A' or 'B', but '0's will always be present (e.g., I could have `['A','K','0']` or `['M','W','0']`, etc.). You can find the example dataset at the bottom of this post.

```
# find x.groups
xs <- unique(myDF$x.group)[unique(myDF$x.group) != "0"]

# DF without '0's as x.group entries
ps <- unique(myDF[which(myDF$x.group %in% xs) , c("ids","x.group","time")])

first3.x1.t1 <- ps[ps$x.group == xs[1] & ps$ids != "0" & ps$time == "1", ]$ids[1:3]
first3.x2.t1 <- ps[ps$x.group == xs[2] & ps$ids != "0" & ps$time == "1", ]$ids[1:3]
first3.x1.t2 <- ps[ps$x.group == xs[1] & ps$ids != "0" & ps$time == "2", ]$ids[1:3]
first3.x2.t2 <- ps[ps$x.group == xs[2] & ps$ids != "0" & ps$time == "2", ]$ids[1:3]
first3.x1.t3 <- ps[ps$x.group == xs[1] & ps$ids != "0" & ps$time == "3", ]$ids[1:3]
first3.x2.t3 <- ps[ps$x.group == xs[2] & ps$ids != "0" & ps$time == "3", ]$ids[1:3]

# First 3 unique ids from time block 1 for each x.group
> first3.x1.t1; first3.x2.t1;
[1] "2"  "17" "11"
[1] "5"  "10" "4"

# First 3 unique ids from time block 2 for each x.group
> first3.x1.t2; first3.x2.t2;
[1] "9"  "6"  "16"
[1] "8"  "13" "7" 

# First 3 unique ids from time block 3 for each x.group
> first3.x1.t3; first3.x2.t3;
[1] "11" "2"  "10"
[1] "1"  "3"  "13"
```

**Data:**

```
# create data frame
ids <- c("2","0","15","5","17","10","4","2","3","11","11","18","10","8","13","9","6","16","7","14",
     "16","7","11","12","14","5","1","11","3","2","10","17","3","13","10","17","2","10","16","10")
x.group <- c("A","A","0","B","A","B","B","A","B","A","A","0","B","B","B","A","A","A","B","B",
         "A","A","0","B","A","B","B","A","B","A","A","0","B","B","B","A","A","A","B","B")
time <- c(rep("1",13), rep("2",13), rep("3",14))

myDF <- as.data.frame(cbind(ids, x.group, time), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> myDF
   ids x.group time
1    2       A    1
2    0       A    1
3   15       0    1
4    5       B    1
5   17       A    1
6   10       B    1
7    4       B    1
8    2       A    1
9    3       B    1
10  11       A    1
11  11       A    1
12  18       0    1
13  10       B    1
14   8       B    2
15  13       B    2
16   9       A    2
17   6       A    2
18  16       A    2
19   7       B    2
20  14       B    2
21  16       A    2
22   7       A    2
23  11       0    2
24  12       B    2
25  14       A    2
26   5       B    2
27   1       B    3
28  11       A    3
29   3       B    3
30   2       A    3
31  10       A    3
32  17       0    3
33   3       B    3
34  13       B    3
35  10       B    3
36  17       A    3
37   2       A    3
38  10       A    3
39  16       B    3
40  10       B    3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
aggregate(ids~.,myDF,function(x)unique(x)[1:3],subset = x.group!="0"&ids!=0)
  x.group time ids.1 ids.2 ids.3
1       A    1     2    17    11
2       B    1     5    10     4
3       A    2     9     6    16
4       B    2     8    13     7
5       A    3    11     2    10
6       B    3     1     3    13
```

This returned a nested dataframe. You can unnest is as:

```
a=aggregate(ids~.,myDF,function(x)unique(x)[1:3],subset = x.group!="0"&ids!=0)
b=do.call(data.frame,a)#The unnested dataframe:
b
  x.group time ids.1 ids.2 ids.3
1       A    1     2    17    11
2       B    1     5    10     4
3       A    2     9     6    16
4       B    2     8    13     7
5       A    3    11     2    10
6       B    3     1     3    13
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)

myDF %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  filter(x.group != "0" & ids != 0) %>% 
  group_by(x.group, time) %>% 
  slice(1:3)

# # A tibble: 18 x 3
# # Groups: x.group, time [6]
#    ids   x.group time 
#    <chr> <chr>   <chr>
#  1 2     A       1    
#  2 17    A       1    
#  3 11    A       1    
#  4 9     A       2    
#  5 6     A       2    
#  6 16    A       2    
#  7 11    A       3    
#  8 2     A       3    
#  9 10    A       3    
# 10 5     B       1    
# 11 10    B       1    
# 12 4     B       1    
# 13 8     B       2    
# 14 13    B       2    
# 15 7     B       2    
# 16 1     B       3    
# 17 3     B       3    
# 18 13    B       3
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the `data.table` solution which I assume should be the fastest; it can be faster by avoiding calling `.SD` for each group.

```
library(data.table)
unique(setDT(myDF))[ids != 0 & x.group!=0, head(.SD, 3), by = list(time, x.group)]


# time x.group ids
# 1:    1       A   2
# 2:    1       A  17
# 3:    1       A  11
# 4:    1       B   5
# 5:    1       B  10
# 6:    1       B   4
# 7:    2       B   8
# 8:    2       B  13
# 9:    2       B   7
# 10:    2       A   9
# 11:    2       A   6
# 12:    2       A  16
# 13:    3       B   1
# 14:    3       B   3
# 15:    3       B  13
# 16:    3       A  11
# 17:    3       A   2
# 18:    3       A  10

microbenchmark(dplyr= {myDF %>% 
    distinct() %>% 
    filter(x.group != "0" & ids != 0) %>% 
    group_by(x.group, time) %>% 
    slice(1:3)},
    aggreagte ={aggregate(ids~.,myDF,function(x)unique(x)[1:3],subset = x.group!="0"&ids!=0)},
    data.table={unique(setDT(myDF))[ids != 0 & x.group!=0, head(.SD, 3), by = list(time, x.group)]})

# Unit: microseconds
# expr      min        lq      mean    median       uq       max neval
# dplyr 6696.740 7025.1780 7911.2968 7229.2430 7500.627 35545.183   100
# aggreagte  920.410  981.9920 1090.5363 1041.1590 1132.627  2801.076   100
# data.table  825.925  894.6005  979.3326  961.3135 1052.329  1267.865   100
```

Comment: @DavidArenburg why? (genuinely asking)

Comment: Because some functions have an overhead when you initiate them. The fact that some function doesn't have a few microseconds overhead on a tiny data set doesn't mean it will scale the same on a huge data set.In other words, a user can't feel this tiny overhead anyway, but they can feel an overhead of minutes vs seconds on big data sets. Hence, benchmarks should be at-least in milliseconds, of not more.