# Subset data based on conditional statement

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, dplyr, subset

I would like to know if there is a way of combining ifelse statement and the filter function (in dplyr package) to subset a data frame. Consider the data

```
df<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3),
            A=c(3,6,2,5,4,3,8,9,8),
           D1=c(0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0),
           D2=c(1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1))
```

I want to delete rows following D2=1 or D1=D2=0 for each id. The expected output would look like

```
df<-data.frame(id=c(1,2,2,2,3),
            A=c(3,5,4,3,9),
           D1=c(0,1,1,0,0),
           D2=c(1,0,0,1,0))
```

I have approached this by several attempts using group_by and the filter function but it appears conditional statements are needed but I'm finding it difficulty to combine these with the filter function. I have come across several Q&A on subsetting data (e.g. [How to subset data by filtering and grouping efficiently in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50769008/how-to-subset-data-by-filtering-and-grouping-efficiently-in-r)) but these do not respond to my question. I greatly appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Do one of the answers address your question, TRichard? If so, please accept one. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `dplyr` , you can find out the first index where the condition is met and select rows which occur before the condition is satisfied for each group.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(row_number() <= which(D1 == 0 & D2 == 0 | D2 == 1)[1])


#     id     A    D1    D2
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     3     0     1
#2     2     5     1     0
#3     2     4     1     0
#4     2     3     0     1
#5     3     9     0     0
```

The above works assuming that at least one row in each group satisfies the condition. A general case, where there might be instances that none of the row satisfies the condition and we want to select all the rows in the group we can use :

```
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  slice({
     inds <- which(D1 == 0 & D2 == 0 | D2 == 1)[1]
     if(!is.na(inds)) -((inds + 1):n()) else seq_len(n())})
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem like you need to use `dplyr` here (unless I'm missing something). Try this:

```
df<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3),
               A=c(3,6,2,5,4,3,8,9,8),
               D1=c(0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0),
               D2=c(1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1))

del = c()

for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  if (df$D2[i] == 1 | (df$D1[i] ==0 & df$D2[i] == 0)){
    del = c(del, i)
  }
}

df = df[del,]
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure `dplyr`:

```r
df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(row_number() == n() | rev(cumany(rev(!(D2 == 1 | (D1 == D2 & D2 == 0))))))
# # A tibble: 5 x 4
# # Groups:   id [3]
#      id     A    D1    D2
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     2     0     0
# 2     2     5     1     0
# 3     2     4     1     0
# 4     2     8     0     1
# 5     3     8     0     1
```